# How to get statistics for multiple videos using Youtube Data APIv3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have a list of video IDs that I want to get the statistics for using **Youtube Data API v3**.

But when I pass a comma separated string that is generated from a list using `','.join(idlist)` to the videos().list() function, it is giving

```
<HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos returned "The request specifies an invalid filter parameter
```

Where am I looking wrong?

Here's the code.

```
idlist = ['OSUxrSe5GbI', 'iMOYZJq6XQo', 'bcHTl9h7TWI', 'qS6F64mj6LY', 'kLpH1nSLJSs']

def video_stats(videoID):
    try:
        print(videoID)
        res = youtube.videos().list(part='snippet, contentDetails, statistics', id=','.join(videoID)).execute()]
        print(','.join(videoID))
        return res
    except Exception as e:
        return e

print(video_stats(idlist))
```

**The list I gave is a sample one. But there are 274 videos in my list. Will there be any limit for number of ids that are being passed?**

Comment: Consider [edit] your question with the built sample request you're making. I think there's a few options about why you're getting this error: either you're passing the `videoId`s with the single quotes, you only will see 50 results per page, or the last element of the array has a comma.

Comment: There is a limit of 50 video IDs per request.